# Combinatorics-Table Arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

How many way can you arrange 10 people in a circle given that 2 particular people cannot sit together?

I'm not sure how to solve this.
I was thinking of maybe $\frac{8!}{10!}$ But I'm pretty sure that's wrong. I really don't understand this.

Comment: how many arrangements forces them to sit together ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you consider rotations (but not reflections) of the circle to be the same arrangement;

Say person A cannot sit next to person B.

Fix a seat for person A. Since we consider rotations as the same, it doesn't matter which one it is, this just defines a place to work from.

Person B can then be placed in any of 7 of the 9 remaining seats (the seven which are not adjacent to A's).

The remaining 8 people can be placed in any order.

This gives a total of $7 \times 8!$ possible arrangements.

If you consider reflections of the circle (as well as rotations) to be the same arrangement, then each appears twice, so the answer is half of this.

If you consider rotations to not be the same arrangement (say you have marked one seat and care who sits there), then each of the given arrangements had 10 possible places where A could have been placed at the start, which gives a total of $10 \times 7 \times 8!$ arrangements.